# Are questions about pure calendar theory on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I just posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270298/is-every-integer-a-possible-year-value) that related to pure calendar theory and technically had no programming involved. There is some discussion in the comments about on topic or not.

I believe this question is on topic because it is about lang-agnostic concepts that are important to know to be a good programmer.

The obvious counter point is that calendar theory is its own topic since it exists firmly outside of programming.

Is this question on topic? If not, where would be a better place to ask?

Comment: It isn't a programming question. There may or may not be a site in the Stack Exchange network where that question could be on-topic, I don't know for sure, but it isn't on-topic here.

Comment: @TinyGiant: but see the comments for a few pressing arguments *for*. Can you refute that "calendar programming" is not something questions should be asked about? (Uh - that's a double negative I realize.)

Comment: I merely stated that it currently *isn't* a programming question. Not that it *couldn't* be a programming question. If you can edit it to be on-topic then by all means do so. As it is, it is not a programming question. @Jongware

Comment: You mean changing it to something like "What integer values should I take care with in my (possibly hypothetical) calender software?" That's an option, yes. But I'll leave it to David to decide.

Comment: This is definitely a question that would have been on-topic 5 or 6 years ago, maybe even 4 years ago.  But things have changed so much in recent years.  The community has narrowed its scope significantly so questions that are just interesting to programmers are much less on-topic as they are not about a **specific** programming problem.  I'd suggest going to [Meta.Programmers.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/) and asking them if it is on-topic there.  Since it is a design consideration, it may be acceptable there.

Comment: The accepted answer says that there is no year `0` in the Gregorian calendar. That might or might not be relevant in a programming context. For example, C's `gmtime()` and `localtime()` functions typically assume that the years `-1`, `0`, and `1` are consecutive (for implementations with 64-bit `time_t`), with the year `-1` corresponding to 2 BCE.

Comment: I started the  kerfuffle by saying "interesting but off topic" I went quiet cos it isn't worth arguing about, but `I believe this question is on topic because it is about lang-agnostic concepts that are important to know to be a good programmer. ` has dragged me back in. It's just wrong. Many programmers never have to worry about dates at all. Very few programmers need to worry about dates at the level of "is every int a year". Step 1 should be built in system date times. Once they fail you you must be getting pretty specialized. I stand by my orig. comment "Interesting question but off topic"

Comment: So a question has to be applicable to a large demographic in order to be classified as on-topic? Does that make all of Jon Skeet's date & time questions and half of the date & time questions he's answered off-topic then since he's one of the only people on SO who specializes in [date](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/date/topusers) [&](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datetime/topusers) [time](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/topusers)? I don't dispute that this question has no programming context, but that doesn't seem like a very strong argument in *itself* for the question being off-topic.

Comment: [(Thankfully, he's not the only one.)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson)

Comment: @John3136: I agree with BoltClock, on-topic does not depend on popularity or number of potential interested users.

Comment: @BoltClock I never claimed demographic size has anything to do with on topic.  The point I meant to make was "detailed date knowledge is not required to be a good programmer" I still say the original question had no programming context and so was off topic.

Comment: @KeithThompson There are no years < 1581 in the Gregorian calendar since it wasn't invented until February 1582 ;)

Comment: @John3136 - but, in your previous comment, expounding on why it was wrong to think the question was on topic, you said "many programmers never have to worry about dates at all.  Very few programmers need to worry about..."  So do you see why people thought you were basing it on demographic size?

Comment: That's not a question about "calendar theory", there's a wholeheckofalot more behind that.  It is a question about data input validation.  Eminently a programming question.  But hey, do yourself a favor and keep it simple, don't accept anything before 1901.

Comment: @agapwlesu As support for the point that being an expert on dates is not necessary for being a good programmer. It's too late for me to edit the comment to try to clarify.

Comment: There is probably no particular knowledge at all that is "required to be a good programmer", beyond the 3 basic programming structures. Witness the very large number of languages of all different paradigms. By this criterion, no questions would qualify.

Comment: Imagine SO had existed in 1999.  It would have been a laughing stock if someone had asked whether 2000 was a leap year only to be told the q was off-topic.  The press would have had a field day.

Answer (score 15):

I've had the same problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099063/what-are-the-ranges-of-coordinates-in-the-cielab-color-space) of mine. The problem I'm asking about in its generality is not strictly programming related.

So in first revision, the contents of the question where explaining the general problem of the range of possible values in CIELAB color space, and the question was put on hold as not programming-related.

The solution was to add a programming example: while it may be unnecessarily narrowing, the general issue is still visible. Putting the problem in a programming context with a code sample makes it on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is an interesting one, and well-written.

I suspect that it's asking about a specific domain of knowledge that is relevant to your work, but isn't a purely programming question.

A similar question would be "Are there people who have only one name, rather than a given name and a family name?" (The answer is yes: for example, members of the Japanese royal family [pubmed link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20231806))

Answer (score -2):

That question, as written, is off topic.  It's just too far off of a programming question, as written.  It's more of a history question than anything else (history.se).

Add the context of input validation, though, and it's entirely on-topic - if you specify a bit more detail.

> When validating input for a YEAR textbox (storing an actual year), are there any integers that I should consider invalid?  I'm writing a HTML page that will be parsed in PHP.

The reason this is important is that the question varies so much by language, as well as logical implementation, that a "pure theory" answer doesn't help a programmer.  The answer in c, in python, in html, etc., would not be the same.  If I'm a c programmer and I see the question and the answer, without the extra context added in that answer (which is a very good one), I end up with a very mistaken belief as to what I can consider a legitimate date value.  [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) is okay when discussing algorithmic implementations and things like that, but it's not a blanket permission to discuss anything that could ever be remotely relevant to a programmer - as that would mean *everything* is on topic.  Questions have to be on topic, regardless of how they're tagged.

Comment: `a "pure theory" answer doesn't help a programmer.` <----  eh. :)

Answer (score -8):

Yes, this question can be considered on topic. Here's why:

We have a lot of questions on the subject of [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date), [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time), [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime), [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone). This one is certainly about dates (and in fact it is tagged so). Of course it is a very particular question, and not many programmers will be interested in it. Still, *some* might be. The OP is just curious, but someone else might need the answer for a program he is working on. Certainly, the author of the original article did find this problem, or it wouldn't be in the list. How can we say it is not about programming?

One more argument: what other professions would ever be interested in the answer to this question? Would a taxi driver, a dentist, a clerk, a photographer, a soldier, a farmer be interested in this? No way. But a programmer, in *some* cases, would. So we can say it is about programming. Of course, probably the category that would find this question the most interesting is historians. Still, that doesn't exclude us.

The fact that only a few users will ever be interested in this shouldn't be a reason for closing, nor for downvoting. This site is full of "please-debug-my-code" questions that are useful to the OP only, and, provided that the question is clear, has a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and shows some effort, that's fine.

And in any case it is an interesting question, why should we ban it? Does its presence harm the site in any way? Would it really bring confusion or lower the quality of the site? No. So let's keep it.

Comment: Your reasoning applies equally well to pretty much any computer usage or administration topic (programmers are significantly more likely to care than a random citizen).  Since that conclusion (that ALL computer questions are on-topic) is universally rejected, look closer and see if you can find the flaw in your reasoning.

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually my reasoning doesn't apply to *any* computer usage. "How do I find the start menu in Windows 8?" is about computer usage but it is off topic, because a programmer would never write a program that finds the start menu. But a programmer could have to write a program that validates dates over a very long period, like if you are finding all eclipses in man's history. Then, knowing that the year 0 doesn't exist is useful.

Comment: We have a [tag:windows] tag, doesn't mean that all [tag:windows] questions are on-topic (which is what you're saying).

Comment: @bob I have clarified what I meant here in the comments, answering to Ben Voigt. And the example I've made is exactly an off-topic question related to Windows! :-)

Comment: @FabioTurati i'm a programmer who has written a program that finds the start menu. your point doesn't work.