# Are formal languages on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Formal languages are well discussed in [Computer Sciences SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). Formal languages are the basic theoretical foundation behind programming, but I'm not sure questions about them are really ABOUT programming.

(Not to mention that many of these questions, when asked on SO, are just asking for us to do their homework, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403847/develop-a-context-sensitive-grammar-that-generates-the-language) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376388/convert-to-chomsky-normal-form). Just a quick glance on [context-free-grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-free-grammar) and the amount of homework is obvious, but that's another topic.)

Are questions about formal languages (assuming they're not low quality like most of them) on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Even if you can you probably should not. If question looks reasonable and on-topic it will likely get a lot of upvotes (looks good/interesting, not idea how to answer), but you are less likely to get answers that you are looking for. Basic grammar questions more likely to get answers as I'd expect a lot of programmers at least tried to build expression parser/basic language parser that way - but I'd expect it to be pretty much boundary of question that will get properly answered on SO.

Comment: Questions about implementing a parser are on topic, which may include "here's some input samples I need to parse, I'm trying this grammar but it matches/doesn't match this other string", but probably not "help me factor this grammar" without any other context.  (Think applied vs. theory.)  Questions about using yacc/bison are on topic.  Questions at home in Sipser's textbook are probably off-topic, and anyway not very likely to get a good answer here.

Comment: A rule of thumb could be: If you want code in a specific programming language in an answer to your question, then the answer is probably on topic. If a valid answer need not contain any actual code then the question should probably be asked on cs.se, because it's only about the theory.

Comment: No it's because your assumption that *"Formal languages are the basic theoretical foundation behind programming"* isn't true. They have nothing to do with programming themselves, as such unless the question has code in it about implementation of them, it is not on topic. Programming languages can be defined based on formal languages, but it's not the other way around. Computer Science is **not** about programming. Basically since it doesn't directly involve programming (unless there is code in the question) then it's off-topic.

Comment: Hmm, while others are thinking about how to get rid of “gimme the code please” questions, you are thinking about rejecting “answers without code are ok” questions… Since SO is *not* a code writing service, it doesn’t make sense to make code in answers mandatory. After all, you *can* provide solutions to a programming problem without providing a single line of code while on the other hand, answers consisting of code only, are considered poor answers…

Comment: @Holger please be more careful with your assumptions. I'm simply asking if those, existing questions, are on-topic or not, to properly flag if necessary. Not at any point I mentioned writing code or not writing code.

Comment: @Mephy: not you (singular), but people commenting your question. Maybe I should have used something like <at> all.

Comment: @Bakuriu There are plenty of valid conceptual questions that require no code (though code often provides conceptual examples). A good rule of thumb perhaps, but one with very common exceptions.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I was considering only the subset of questions related to grammars and I believe in this case that rule of thumb is pretty accurate.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**No.**

*Stack Overflow* is about computer programming, not computer science.

Working in formal languages is not computer programming. It is "doing science".

Ask your Computer Science questions on *Computer Science*.

Comment: ... unless doing computer science might sometimes involve doing some computer programming.

Comment: @Haspemulator: Then it's on-topic for the same reason that creating a coffee machine involves doing some computer programming, even though SO is not CoffeeMachines.se :)

Comment: For the amount of coffee we consume as a collective.. maybe questions about coffee should be on topic here! ;)

Comment: Did anyone ever spot a coffee related question tagged with [javabeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javabeans)?

Comment: There *is* a [tag:coffee] tag.

Answer (score 18):

"Theoretical foundation": that's your key right there. It's like saying physics is the theoretical foundation of construction, so should a physics questions belong on a SE about home construction & renovation? The answer is almost never.

True, you might have a question about syntax of some programming language and refer to its formal grammar, or about how to implement some formal grammar using a library, but that is the extent of it. If the question is primarily about programming and incidentally about formal languages, then that is fine, but the same could be said of  music theory, colour theory, number theory, etc.

Comment: ... and [calendars](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308542/2564301) ...